# Grease Pencil: All colors render black in Eevee

Tags: grease-pencil

OMG - so obvious, thanks again, @Crantisz.

---

Another GP-noop question: All colors render black in Eevee. Tried several approaches including resetting stroke colors in Vertex paint but no success. What can I do?

Kind regards, Raaskot

[image: Color render all in black]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Grease Pencil reacts to light. If you don't have any, it will look black, as any mesh object without proper lightning. If you want Grease Pencil to be shadless, disable this function in all layers:

[image]